# How to send parameters with JSP?

Tags: jsp

I have an index jsp. How can I send parameters to some bean from the index page so that the second page genereted some data depending on the sent parameters ?

---

Here is my index.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World! qqqqq</h1>
        <form name="Input Name Form" action="response.jsp"/>
        <p> Enter your name:</p>
           <input type="text" name="name"/>  
           <input type="submit"   value="ok" />
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

my response.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <jsp:useBean id="aaa" scope="page" class="A.a" />
        <jsp:setProperty name="aaa" property="name" value="<%= request.getParameter("set")%>" />
        <jsp:getProperty name="aaa" property="name" />

    </body>
</html>
```

and my A.a bean:

```
public class a {
    public a ()
    {}
    private String name;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String get() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void set(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

GlassFish says:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6054: Cannot find any information on property 'name' in a bean of type 'A.a'

What's wrong ? Why do my program do not work ??

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very 'loose' question and needs a more concise request.

Comment: Uhm.... I'm just trying to ask if it is possible to pass some parameters to invocation of  a bean in the scond page.

Comment: The problem is that it shows no effort on your part to solve the problem. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for pointers on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Changed question a little bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects a [*property*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html) in the Java bean jargon, i.e. you should provide these methods:

```
public void setName(String s) { ... }

public String getName() { ... }
```